# Ajax script not loading anything and no requests being sent

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This script is supposed to run a jQuery Ajax script every second, it is supposed to fetch all newer posts then put them on top of the original ones. But at the moment nothing is happening, it loads the initial posts but nothing else. Firebug console is reporting no errors, or no Ajax requests being sent at all. Can you see anything wrong with this script at all that could cause this? Thanks :)

Source code - 
index.php(i left out css):

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Twitter Style load more results.</title>
<link href="frame.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(function () {
        setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 1000);
    });

    function oneSecondFunction() {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        if (ID) {
            $("#more" + ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_more.php",
                data: "lastmsg=" + ID,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("ol#updates").prepend(html);
                    $("#more" + ID).remove();
                }
            });
        } else {

        }


        return false;


    };
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id='container'>
  <ol class="timeline" id="updates">
<?php
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from updates ORDER BY item_id DESC LIMIT 9");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $msg_id=$row['item_id'];
        $message=$row['item_content'];
?>
<li>
  <?php echo $message; ?>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax_more.php -

```
 <?php
include("config.php");


if(isset($_POST['lastmsg']))
{
    $lastmsg=$_POST['lastmsg'];
    $result=mysql_query("select * from updates where item_id<'$lastmsg' order by item_id desc limit 9");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $msg_id=$row['item_id'];
        $message=$row['item_content'];
?>


<li>
  <?php echo $message; ?>
</li>


<?php
    }


?>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and walk through the code?

Comment: I've looked through it allot. I'm not too experienced in jQuery.

Comment: I don't see where the actual function is being called.

Comment: what is 'this' in "var ID = $(this).attr("id");"

Comment: **Warning:** be aware of possible SQL injections where you use user entered parameters in your queries, like in `select * from updates where item_id<'$lastmsg' order by item_id desc limit 9`.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel my_real_escape_string ftw!

Comment: @Chris: it's [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) and he doesn't use it at the moment.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel oops, typo! I know he doesn't use it at the moment I was just stating for others that get concerned with your comment.  (PS - Not every comment is posted with the intent of bashing the person in the @field)

Comment: @Chris: yeah, I already thought it was a mistake and I thought I overlooked something, no problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the code in the beginning looks wrong. This should work. It will call the oneSecondFunction every second:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 1000);


  function oneSecondFunction() {
    //console.log('run oneSecondFunction');
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    if(ID) {
      $("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');  
      $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "ajax_more.php", data: "lastmsg="+ ID,  cache: false,
               success: function(html){
                 $("ol#updates").prepend(html);
                 $("#more"+ID).remove();
               }
              });
    } else {  
    }   return false;   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i quoted out the section where it gets the id, because 'this' wasn't referring to anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    setInterval(oneSecondFunction, 1000);
});

function oneSecondFunction() {
    //var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var ID = '1';
    if(ID){
        $("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_more.php",
            data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ol#updates").prepend(html);
                $("#more"+ID).remove();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```